# Converting UTF-8 hex to Unicode hex

Tags: r, string, unicode, utf-8

I have strings such as "flamenguistas e s\xc3a3o paulinos", containing UTF-8 codes in this manner "\xc3a3". How do I turn this into the letter "ã"?

I'm having trouble because most functions for un-escaping expect codes to be Unicode and I haven't been able to find a proper manner to convert the UTF-8 hex to the Unicode hex.

Is there an easy way to transform UTF-8 hex to Unicode hex aside from writing a function reading from a table and converting?

P.S. When I say "Unicode hex"/"UTF-8 hex" I mean as in here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%87#Computer

Comment: It would help if you provided actual code showing the definition of such a string. The simple reason is, that there are multiple places where things could be escaped or interpreted. Having code, no interpretation is necessary, so give an example of both what you have and what you need. As general advise to a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: "\xc3a3" seems strange. Are you sure it's not "\xc3\xa3"? And is that just a "dump-to-string" rendering of bytes? That is, does the string contain a backslash and x, or does it contain a byte with the value of c3 (hexadecimal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like R has support for PCRE regex. You can port the following substitution.

The hex function takes a string of hex digits and converts it into a number. The chr function takes a number and turns it into a character. The dot operator is string concatenation. The whole result consists of UTF-8 encoded octets.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
$_ = <<'';
flamenguistas e s\xc3a3o paulinos

s|
    \\x             # literal \x
    (               # capture into $1
        [0-9a-f]    # hex digits
        {2}         # exactly two times
    )
    (               # capture into $2
        [0-9a-f]
        {2}
    )
|
    chr(hex($1)) . chr(hex($2))
|egmsx;

print; # flamenguistas e são paulinos
```